# How to write a Linux script to run multiple files from a single executable?

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file

I have an executable which works on a file & produces another file. I need to provide the first entry of the file as an argument of the executable. Suppose the executable name is "myexec" and I am trying to run a file "myfile.extension"
"myfile.extension" has a format like this:

```
7 4 9 1 4 11 9 2 33 4 7 1 22 4 55 ...
```

While running the executable, I have to type the following:

myexec 7 myfile.extension

and it produces a file named myfile.extension.7

My question is that how can I write a script that will do this for a bunch of files in a directory?

Comment: please remove the tag batch-file, as that strictly applies to windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bash script that you can execute in the directory with the files. It assumes the first word in the file is the argument:

```
for f in *
do 
   i=$(awk 'NR==1{print $1;exit}' $f)
   myexec $i myfile.extension
done
```

Edit: Using `awk` instead of `cut | head`. Mentioned by brianadams in the comments.

Comment: Thanks!
Will it run for all files? 
I mean if I have myfile1, myfile2, myfile3,... then it should work on all files & produce different outputs.

Comment: It should run for all files in the directory you run it in. That's what the [loop](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html) does

Comment: `$(awk 'NR==1{print $1;exit}' $f)`, or `read -r firstline<file; i=${firstline%% *}`

Comment: `myexec $i "$f.$i"`. Also you could drop `in *` to allow specifying files via `"$@"` (command-line).